# What is the Javascript equivalent of a Class variable?

Tags: javascript, class, instance, instance-variables, class-variables

Edit: Thanks @Aadit M Shah for confirming.

```
function Apple () {}
Apple.someVar = null; // Class variable
Apple.prototype.someVar = null; // Instance variable
```

Comment: Yes, `Apple.someVar` is effectively a "class variable".

Comment: I don't know which language the phrase 'class variable' is from, but `Apple.prototype.someVar` is the property and value that will be passed on to instances of `Apple`, not `Apple.someVar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is a functional language and features of classical programming languages are not directly supported but can be achieved by the concept of closures.

In the code snippet you gave, both Apple.someVar and Apple.prototype.someVar will have the same value for all objects created from the Apple constructor function, i.e. like a class variable.

To achieve the functionality of instance variables, use closures.
You can look online for more help on closures, here's reference http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

I am providing a small code snippet to to make it clear.

```
function Apple(property){
  var color = property.color; //instance variable
  this.getColor = function(){
    return color;
 };  
}
Apple.type = "fruit"; //class variable

var redApple = new Apple({color:'red'});
var greenApple = new Apple({color:'green'});
```

both the variables redApple and greenApple share the same property 'type' but each has its own color property.

Comment: The code snippet doesn't use closures at all.

Comment: Your "closure" example isn't really using closures. You don't need the local `color` variable. (If you defined a `this.someMethod = function() {}` method inside `Apple()` that used `color` *then* you'd be using a closure.)

Comment: I just wanted to give a simplified version of using closures to achieve the instance variable concept. A more better way would be to use getters to obtain the value of the color property

Answer (score 7):

In class-based languages (i.e. Java) static members are created with a special syntax and can be used as if they were members of the class itself.

In JavaScript there is no special syntax to denote static properties. However you can implement such a classy behaviour by using constructor function and adding properties to it. Constructors, like all other functions, are objects and can have properties.

Let's see an example:

We have a constructor for Car, a static method for Car and an "instance" (prototype delegation) method for Car.

```
// constructor
var Car = function () {};

// a static method
Car.isShiny = function () {
  return "bling bling";
};

// "instance" method added to the prototype
Car.prototype.setPrice = function (price) {
  this.price = price;
};
```

As expected we can call the static method and the "instance" method.

```
// calling a static method
Car.isShiny(); // "bling bling"

// creating an instance and calling a method
var ford = new Car();
ford.setPrice(5000);
```

Calling an "instance" method statically won't work.
Similarly, calling a static method on an instance won't work.

```
typeof Car.setPrice; // "undefined"
typeof ford.isShiny; // "undefined"
```

There is a workaround for calling a static method on an instance. Define a prototype method, which references the static method.

```
Car.prototype.isShiny = Car.isShiny;
ford.isShiny(); // "bling bling"
```

However, this comes with a little complication that we need to be aware of. The keyword `this`, if used in the static method, will refer to either the `Car` constructor function or the `ford` instance, depending on who is the caller.

It is possible to have the same method called statically and non-statically. With the help of `instanceof` we can know how the method was called.

```
// constructor
var Car = function (price) {
  this.price = price;
};

// a static method
Car.isShiny = function () {
  
  // this always works
  var msg = "bling bling";
  
  if (this instanceof Car) {
    // this only works if called non-statically
    msg += ", it costs $" + this.price + '!';
  }
  
  return msg;
};

// a normal method added to the prototype
  Car.prototype.isShiny = function () {
  return Car.isShiny.call(this);
};

// static call
Car.isShiny(); // "bling bling"

//non static call
var benz = new Car('9999.99');
benz.isShiny(); // "bling bling, it costs $9999.99!"
```

The example illustrates the use of public static members. In JavaScript you can implement private static members too.

Reference: JavaScript Patterns book.

Comment: Should `this instanceof Gadget` be `this instanceof Car`?

Comment: You are right. Thx for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
function Apple () {}
Apple.someVar = null; // property on the constructor - doesn't affect instances
Apple.prototype.someVar = null; // the default value of the `someVar` property on instances returned by the constructor when using the `new` keyword
```

Here is a more verbose example to see it in action:

```
function Apple () {}

Apple.color = 'blue'; // this doesn't do what you think it does.

console.log('Apple.color:', Apple.color); // blue

console.log('---'); 

// basic instantiation of the apples
var goldenDelicious = new Apple();
var grannySmith = new Apple();
var fuji = new Apple();

console.log('goldenDelicious.color:', goldenDelicious.color); // undefined
console.log('grannySmith.color:', grannySmith.color); // undefined
console.log('fuji.color:', fuji.color); // undefined

console.log('---'); 

fuji.color = 'red';

Apple.prototype.color = 'green'; 
// overrides color properties of all apples that have not 
// had their color set - even those of instances already created
// This is because their value is the default, and we are 
// modifying that default.

console.log('goldenDelicious.color:', goldenDelicious.color); // green
console.log('grannySmith.color:', grannySmith.color); // green
console.log('fuji.color:', fuji.color); // red

console.log('---'); 

// assign some actual colors

goldenDelicious.color = 'yellow';
grannySmith.color = 'green';
fuji.color = 'red';

console.log('goldenDelicious.color:', goldenDelicious.color); // yellow
console.log('grannySmith.color:', grannySmith.color); // green
console.log('fuji.color:', fuji.color); // red

console.log('---'); 

Apple.prototype.color = 'orange'; // all new apples will default to orange

var honeyCrisp = new Apple();

console.log('goldenDelicious.color:', goldenDelicious.color); // yellow
console.log('grannySmith.color:', grannySmith.color); // green
console.log('fuji.color:', fuji.color); // red
console.log('honeyCrisp.color:', honeyCrisp.color); // orange
```